# Modify and run nose Doctest Plugin

Tags: python-3.x, nose

I have been using `nose.run(argv=['--with-doctest'], addplugins=[...])` successfully but now I am needing to subclass `nose.plugins.doctests.Doctest` so that I can modify its  `loadTestsFromModule` method. I have other plugins (by subclassing `nose.plugins.Plugin`) which are working, but I have not been successful run the doctests.

```py
from nose.plugins.doctests import Doctest

class TestDocs(Doctest):
    def loadTestsFromModule(self, module):
        # add something here
        super(testDocs, self).__init__(module)
```

I have tried the following:

```py
nose.run(addplugins=[TestDocs()])
nose.run(plugins=[TestDocs()])
nose.run(argv=['--with-testdocs'])
nose.run(argv=['--with-testdocs'], addplugins=[TestDocs()])
```

I also tried another name, in case it including 'test' was an issue. And I tried using `DocTest` directly, but have been unable to activate doctests without using `--with-doctest`.

```
nose.run(addplugins=[Doctest()])
nose.run(plugins=[Doctest()])
```

How can I activate doctests using the plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This combination allowed for the custom subclass of `Doctest` using `nose.run`.

```
nose.run(argv=['--with-testdocs'], plugins=[TestDocs()])
```

It was helpful to use `argv=['--plugins']` as it highlighted the difference between `plugins=` and `addplugins=` since I was already using addplugins for other Plugins.:

```
>>> nose.run(argv=['--plugins'], plugins=[TestDocs()], 
             addplugins=[OtherPlugin(), AnotherPlugin()])
Plugin OtherPlugin
Plugin testdocs
Plugin AnotherPlugin
```